# How does short-circuiting work in std::conjunction

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, metaprogramming

Given the following code (https://wandbox.org/permlink/Eof3RQs49weJMWan)

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto always_false = false;

template <typename T>
class HardError {
    static_assert(always_false<T>);
};

int main() {
    std::ignore = std::conjunction<std::false_type, HardError<int>>{};
}
```

I am trying to understand why this does not error out with `std::conjunction` as used above.  I understand that it is meant to allow short-circuiting so this does not happen, and that this is by design.

However, I don't understand the language rules that allow this to happen.  Given the implementation of `std::conjunction` below

```
template<class...> struct conjunction : std::true_type { };
template<class B1> struct conjunction<B1> : B1 { };
template<class B1, class... Bn>
struct conjunction<B1, Bn...> 
    : std::conditional_t<bool(B1::value), conjunction<Bn...>, B1> {};
```

We end up inheriting from this specialization of `std::conditional`

```
template<class T, class F>
struct conditional<false, T, F> { typedef F type; };
```

This requires both class types for instantiation.  Then how is the `conjunction<Bn...>` elided by the language?

Comment: Now, add `typedef HardError<int> zz;` to your sample code. This will also compile without any errors. Now, try to instantiate `zz`, only ***then*** you get an error. Just because a class with a failed static assertion is referenced doesn't trigger the static assertion, but when you attempt to create an instance of the class. No instance of `HardError` gets instantiated during the unraveling of `std::conjunction`.

Comment: In addition, I think it is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, according to [\[temp.res\]/8.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#8.1)

Answer (score 4):

cppreference (the page you pulled that implementation from) provides an [explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction) for how it works:

> Conjunction is short-circuiting: if there is a template type argument `Bi` with `bool(Bi::value) == false`, then instantiating `conjunction<B1, ..., BN>::value` does not require the instantiation of `Bj::value` for `j > i`.

Concretely, we can see this in action. Your line in main:

```
std::ignore = std::conjunction<std::false_type, HardError<int>>{};
```

is equivalent to:

```
std::ignore.operator=(conjunction<std::integral_constant<bool, 0>, HardError<int> >{{}});
```

Which should cause an instantiation, something like the following:

```
template<>
struct conjunction<std::integral_constant<bool, 0>, HardError<int> > : public std::integral_constant<bool, 0>
{
  inline ~conjunction() noexcept = default;

};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) I understand that something like this instantiation would be created by the compiler.  I am trying to understand what language rules lead to this not being ill formed.

Answer (score 2):

The instantiation of a template does *not* trigger the instantiation of its template arguments. See [[temp.inst/2]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#2)

This is a typical way to delay hard error.

```
template<class T> struct delay {
    using run = T;
};

int main() {
    // force instantiation of delay<HardError<int>>,
    // but HardError<int> itself is not instantiated
    sizeof(delay<HardError<int>>);

    delay<HardError<int>> a; // OK, same as above

    // Now HardError<int> is instantiated, static_assert failure
    // sizeof(delay<HardError<int>>::run);
}
```

For the same reason, the instantiation of `std::conditional<false, int, HardError<int>>` won't cause the instantiation of `HardError<int>`

Furthermore, the template argument doesn't even need to be complete.

The following code is also valid:

```
struct incomplete_tag;

int main() { sizeof(delay<incomplete_tag>); }
```